# How to use OpenVPN environmental variables for inline scripts?

Tags: scripting, openvpn

I'm trying to use environmental variables offered by OpenVPN inline.

This works just fine:

OpenVPN client config:

```
[...]
up /tmp/script.sh
[...]
```

/tmp/script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $ifconfig_remote
```

However, if I try to do that inline, in the configuration file it doesn't work.

OpenVPN client config:

```
[...]
up '/bin/echo $ifconfig_remote'
[...]
```

It literally prints `$ifconfig_remote`. I've also tried to enclose it in `${ifconfig_remote}` or back-ticks.

Is there a way to access/print environmental variables, without the use of external scripts?

Comment: Are you using this to log clients connecting and disconnecting?

Comment: @callisto i honestly don't remember anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like OpenVPN directly `exec()`s the given command, rather than passing it to the shell. The result is that you don't get shell interpolation, which in your case means your variables are used literally.

If you don't want to use a script, try explicitly calling the shell:

```
up '/bin/sh -c "echo $ifconfig_remote"'
```